# why the MaxHeapSize values are different between java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal and jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize

Tags: java, docker, jvm, heap-memory

I'm running my java application on apline linux system in docker container, and I wanna find out the value of MaxHeapSize, so I use several command : java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal, jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize , jmap -heap, but the output made me feel confused. The output of
jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize , jmap -heap are consistent. However, The output of java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal is different.so why did this happen?

The default container memory Limit setting is 4096MiB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZqRJ.png)

The output of java commonds is shown below.(I marked some important parts in the picture)

```
bash-5.0# jps -v
9 jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0 -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=20.0 -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:log/gc-%t.log -Duser.timezone=Asia/Shanghai -Delastic.apm.service_name=SUPER-STUDENTS -Delastic.apm.environment=k8s-prod-th-zhidao-manhattan -Delastic.apm.server_urls= -Delastic.apm.trace_methods= -Delastic.apm.trace_methods_duration_threshold=100ms -Delastic.apm.application_packages=outfox -Delastic.apm.capture_body=all -Delastic.apm.ignore_message_queues=* -Delastic.apm.profiling_inferred_spans_enabled=true -Delastic.apm.profiling_inferred_spans_sampling_interval=10ms -Delastic.apm.profiling_inferred_spans_min_duration=50ms -Dskywalking.agent.service_name=super-students -Dskywalking.agent.instance_name=super-students-75f964dbbd-5gfnv -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1234
64155 Jps -Dapplication.home=/opt/java/openjdk -Xms8m
bash-5.0# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -Ei "maxheapsize|maxram"
    uintx DefaultMaxRAMFraction                     = 4                                   {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1073741824                          {product}
 uint64_t MaxRAM                                    = 137438953472                        {pd product}
    uintx MaxRAMFraction                            = 4                                   {product}
   double MaxRAMPercentage                          = 25.000000                           {product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
bash-5.0# jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize 9
-XX:MaxHeapSize=2577399808
bash-5.0# jmap -heap 9
Attaching to process ID 9, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.282-b08

using thread-local object allocation.
Garbage-First (G1) GC with 1 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 2577399808 (2458.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 1545601024 (1474.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 1048576 (1.0MB)

Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
   regions  = 2458
   capacity = 2577399808 (2458.0MB)
   used     = 320120112 (305.2903289794922MB)
   free     = 2257279696 (2152.709671020508MB)
   12.420273758319455% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
   regions  = 53
   capacity = 654311424 (624.0MB)
   used     = 55574528 (53.0MB)
   free     = 598736896 (571.0MB)
   8.493589743589743% used
Survivor Space:
   regions  = 10
   capacity = 10485760 (10.0MB)
   used     = 10485760 (10.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
   regions  = 247
   capacity = 389021696 (371.0MB)
   used     = 254059824 (242.2903289794922MB)
   free     = 134961872 (128.7096710205078MB)
   65.30736630174992% used

63962 interned Strings occupying 6772928 bytes.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Nlm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not comparing the same thing.

When running `jmap` or `jstack`, these attach to the existing process with PID 9, as listed in the first `jps` command.

When running `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version`, this creates a new JVM process, and prints the information for that new process. Note that the original PID 9 process has a number of additional flags that can affect the calculated heap size.

For a more accurate comparison, you could add the `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` flags to the main command run when the container starts. I would expect this to match the values returned by `jinfo` and `jmap`.

Comment: As you said , I added ```-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal``` to command line options and restart container, now I found  uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 2577399808                          {product}  in the logs, thank you!